# Different results between TensorFlow and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following code snippet. A a lot of Sigma matrices are generated by a neural network and these matrices have to be positive definite. So that is checked in the debug function.

What is weird is that Sigma2 does not give a *** LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite error, where Sigma does. To be complete, the first 1499 iterations everything goes well.

But np.sum(np.abs(Sigma-Sigma2)) gives a value of 19687.622918061788. So it seems like the Sigma constructed in Tensorflow has different values than the Sigma2 generated in Numpy. How is this possible?

```
# Because there is no tensorflow equivalent for np.eye()
identity = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.eye(mu_shape[-1].value), dtype=tf.float32))
Sigma = tf.batch_matmul(L,tf.matrix_transpose(L)) + 1e-4*identity

# Check positive definite
def _debug_print_func(Sigma,L):
  try:            
    C = np.linalg.cholesky(Sigma)
  except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
    Sigma2 = np.matmul(L,np.transpose(L,axes=[0,1,3,2]))+1e-4*np.eye(4)) 
    print 'LinAlgError'  
    # Sigma different from Sigma2??
    pdb.set_trace()
    return False

debug_print_op = tf.py_func(_debug_print_func, [Sigma,L], [tf.bool])
with tf.control_dependencies(debug_print_op):
  Sigma = tf.identity(Sigma, name='out')
```

Edit:
Also a small numeric example

In the debug function I compute

```
W=np.matmul(L[0,0,:,:],L[0,0,:,:].T)+1e-4*np.eye(4)
```

Then I do

```
Sigma[0,0,:,:]-W
```

Sigma[0,0,:,:]-W gives

```
array([[ -2.39243686e-05,  -2.29620725e-05,   1.46458477e-05,  2.68967569e-05],
       [ -2.29620725e-05,  -3.72494698e-05,   2.18125388e-05,  3.86031806e-05],
       [  1.46458477e-05,   2.18125388e-05,  -3.83383453e-05,  2.45112851e-05],
       [  2.68967569e-05,   3.86031806e-05,   2.45112851e-05,  -5.60631990e-05]])
```

So all the elements seems to have a difference in the order of 1e-5 between Numpy and TensorFlow. This seems to make the difference between positive definite or not.

Is this a bug in TensorFlow or is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Not sure if this is what's happening here, but the parallel implementations of some operations like batch_matmul can be slightly nondeterministic due to floating point precision issues.