# Tensorflow: Unexpected behaviour

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I run the same training script twice, with completely different results. The only difference is the Python operation inserted with this code

```
# Add a small amount times the identity matrix to prevent errors
identity = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.eye(mu_shape[-1].value), dtype=tf.float32))
Sigma = tf.batch_matmul(L,tf.matrix_transpose(L)) + 1e-4*identity

# Check positive definite
def _debug_print_func(Sigma,L):
  try:
      C = np.linalg.cholesky(Sigma)
  except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
      print 'LinAlgError'  

  return Sigma

[Sigma] = tf.py_func(_debug_print_func, [Sigma,L], [tf.float32])
```

So when the last line is commented out the error decreases to ~-40 while (than a not positive definite error occurs). With the Python operation (that actually does not nothing) the error has a very different value.

What could explain this behaviour? I ran this a lot of times, with this same phenomena each time

[image]

Comment: Your initial random weights might have made a difference ?

Comment: NumPy guy here, not a TensorFlow guy, but why are you assigning to `[Sigma]`? That's a very unusual thing to do.

Comment: could you add more code (ie, what does your loop and session.run calls look like)

Comment: @user2357112 It is indeed unusual and was first to debug things. But now this extra Python operator ( that does return the same as the input) affects the result significantly.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It is part of a large training script, but the looks and sess.run calls look normal

Comment: Are you sure you understand what the brackets there do?

Comment: I added the brackets, because otherwise I had to type Sigma[0] in the lines following?

Comment: I wonder if there's something funky going on with Sigma getting copied from TF runtime then to Python runtime, then back to TF runtime. You could rule that out by keeping Sigma unchanged and using control_dependencies to do the debug print

Comment: The idea was to replace the Sigma by the result of the Numpy computation, if the Tensorflow one is not positive definite. The Numpy Sigma is then positive definite with the same computation in Numpy. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975722/different-results-between-tensorflow-and-numpy